# why when i imported 200k data only 7k imported?

Tags: sql, sql-server, navicat

Why when i import/input 100k data, why only 7k data imported?

I already tried to change the length, its only 7k imported

> [Err] [Imp] 22001 - [SQL Server]String or binary data would be
>   truncated. 01000 - [SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.
>
> [Msg] [Imp] Processed:7587, Added:7403, Updated:0, Deleted:0,
>   Errors:184 [Msg] [Imp] Finished - Unsuccessfully

while i have 197.511 data to import

Comment: You should look at the next record after the last one imported, that's where the truncation would occur causing your import to quit. It should be the 7404th record (7403 + 1)

Comment: the error seems clear, you are trying to update more characters into a column than this column can handle. Without more info from you however, nobody can answer this question exact. How do you import ?

Comment: the record 7404 just same values with diffrent PK @LittleSweetSeas

Comment: i import with import wizard navicat @GuidoG

Comment: Like the others have said, you have a value that won't fit in your (what I assume is) `varchar` column and so the `INSERT` fails. Must likely you have a column that isn't wide enough.